# Editing a Button's colour in a nonUI thread (Android)

Tags: java, multithreading, android

I've seen some similar questions and got some information but they stop shy of telling me enough to get it working.

What I'm trying to do is make a simple rhythm game where the player taps a button at regular intervals (ie. beats). I wanted to set up a way of signalling when to tap by having the button change colour, and since this would be a repeated task at regular intervals I want to use a timer object with a schedule method.

But when I try calling on this method it tells me that I can't change the UI in a non UI thread. I've tried a few ways to write a method in the main thread that I can call from the timer object but I get the same error every time. I'm assuming that I just have the wrong idea about what counts as being from the UI thread, so I was hoping someone could clear it up.

Here's a snippet of one way I tried it, just to show what my code looks like:

```
OnClickListener clickButton = new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (startBeat == 0){
        startBeat = System.nanoTime();
        timerStart.scheduleAtFixedRate((new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                flashButton();
            }
        }), 0, beatTime);               
        timerEnd.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                unflashButton();
            }
        }, beatTolerance*2, beatTime);              
        return;
    }
};

public void flashButton(){
    beatPrompt.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary1transparent_very));
}
public void unflashButton(){
    beatPrompt.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary1));
}
```

To be clear, this is all contained within my MainActivity class along with the OnCreate class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are in an activity all you need to do is use `runOnUiThread()` and then place the code to change the ui element in there

```
public void flashButton(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                beatPrompt.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary1transparent_very));
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, under any circumstances, touch a UI object from a non UI thread.

You can accomplish your intent using `Handler.sendMessageDelayed`

Answer (score 0):

UI can only be touched by the main thread. You should post the actions you are performing on the ui thread via `handler` or via `runOnUiThread`

Try something similar to this

```
timerStart.scheduleAtFixedRate((new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            //replace MainActivity with your activity
            //if inside a fragment use getActivity()
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                flashButton();
               }
            });
        }
    }), 0, beatTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an Activity you could surround flashButton() with an runOnUiThread.

```
...
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
      flashButton();
  }
});

...
```

Answer (score 0):

use `android.os.Handler` Class. Change your code as follows:

```
private Handler handler=new Handler();

public void flashButton(){
    handler.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            beatPrompt.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary1transparent_very));
        }
    });
}
public void unflashButton(){
    handler.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            beatPrompt.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary1));
        }
    });
}
```